# After I murdered/robbed people, how do I get rid of the bounty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I thought it would be nice to steal some useful stuff from people. However, the whole town got angry for me doing so. Seems someone did spot me doing so, I survived the first people by walking back out of the town and had to murder three man where I used up all my potions. When entering the town again I entered a building but the immediate moment I enter the building an angry person also enters right behind me and is much stronger than me. I don't seem welcome in this town anymore...

Here are my questions:

- What should I do to survive from him and get rid of the bounty?
- Can I run out of the town for a long distance so I lose aggro or bounty? Or will he keep following?

Comment: Lose aggro? They're not mobs. They're people! People like to hold grudges.

Comment: In Makarath, it does not give you the option to pay any gold OR go to jail.... actually when you select to go to jail, it just keeps repeating the dialogue. Possibley a glitch OR mission related?

Comment: There *is* a questline which involves enjoying the prison's hospitality.  It's possible that it can bug out the arrest dialogue.

Comment: i have a 57 gold bounty in riverwood and i need to go there to finish the horn of the person all i stole was a mace from the blacksmith and now his crazy wife is after me too i didn't kill them i ran can i just avoid them and go up to a guard a pay the bounty?

Comment: @sam: While holding the block key walk up to a guard and try to interact with him, it should give the menu. If not, you have a problem and should just stay way till the bounty is lower.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Crime is generally localized to the hold you're in: if you are kill-on-sight in one hold, running to the next hold over should cause the guards to drop pursuit without new guards joining the chase.

However, in general, you should always be able to pay the guards, even if they decide to attack you. As soon as they do, sheathe your weapons/spells/shields and hope they trigger the dialogue to allow you to go to jail or pay off your bounty.

If they don't, there are a few things you can try to do:

- As [Bri](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39190/3389) and [RoughNeckRage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38993/3389) mention, sometimes all you need is time. Wait out a few days and see if the situation hasn't died down by then. The guards will still want you to make reparations, though.
- An anonymous user mentions that you can try sneaking up to a guard from behind and trigger the dialogue screen to pay off your bounty.
- [Stof mentions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38993/3389) another possible thing, the bounty collector. The [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Jail#Bounty_collector) suggests it's not guaranteed, but if he does visit you, you can pay off your bounty for a 20% premium (and even keep your stolen items!).

Comment: Running around the building then exiting the town from where I entered and running and hiding a bush was sufficient to lose him, then using the wait feature set to 2 made it night and he doesn't seem to go after me. Thanks!

Comment: Hm...they "forgot" when I killed the town's entire supply of guards

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally killed a guard while slaying a dragon and then after the dragon was dead the gaurds turned on me well I killed them but I didn't want to have to load my last save and not have the dragon soul or all the items I aquired from the dragon, troll, and dead gaurds so what I did when coast was clear was wait 24 hours and then slept for 12 hours and then fast travelled back into to town a gaurd approached me and said "you look familiar" and it gave me the opition to say no i don't well then he said I could go to jail pay fee or fight him so I paid my 40 gold bounty and he searched me for stolen items. Well that was the best way to do it I think. So try that and I hope it helps but waiting is the big thing!

Answer (score 3):

Eat glowing mushrooms then go to whiterun, talk to Olfrid, give him a bottle of mead and he pays off the guards in Riverwood.

Comment: im curious if this auctually does something

Answer (score 3):

Supposedly (I never got a bounty THAT high), if you get a really high bounty to the point guards kill you first and talk later, you can still pay it back. Avoid the town and just continue playing in the rest of the world. An NPC bounty hunter will come after you and he'll actually talk first, giving you the option to pay the bounty and it'll clear it up.

Answer (score 3):

Leave town and wait 48 hours if all the people are attacking you in the town. If not the guards tend to glitch just keep taking your weapon out and putting it away until they give you an option to pay bounty.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to get lost of the bounty and don't mind a bit of cheating;

First add some money with 'player.additem f [amount]' without the brackets into the console - though I'm not sure if this'll work on consoles.

Then sheathe your weapon and approach a guard. Most of the time they'll ask you to pay the fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen videos of where to get rid of your bounty, all you have to do is kill every witness of your crime.  This can be extremely hard to do if you flee the scene.  But if you kill a guard, might as well kill all guards and all witnesses.  Then your bounty will be removed.