# Where did the guy that helped me escape the Helgen dragon go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After escaping the dragon in the beginning of the game, some guy whose name I don't remember was helping me escape the dragon, and took me through a first area all the way to Riverwood. This is where I decided [to try out stealing stuff](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/after-i-stole-their-stuff-how-do-i-survive-from-angry-people); I killed the first three guys that chased me and entered a building afterwards, after which a fourth guy killed me. I didn't pay attention to the guy helping me...

Now, I have some questions:

- Did he get killed in the background? Did he turn against me? Or did he end his journey with me?
- What would have happened if I didn't go stealing wild but rather kept following his instructions?

Comment: Did you go to Riverwood?

Comment: Yes, that is where I seem to have lost him. But I don't know why/how he went away...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you go to Riverwood, go up the hill. You will find Hod and Gerdur's house. If Ralof is alive, he walks there after escorting you through the keep. You can also find him sitting at the stump next the the mill talking to Gerdur.

Comment: Ralof is misspelled and there's another location in the beginning where he is so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you went with Hadvar the imperial, he will be at the blacksmith's house. If you went with Ralof the Stormcloak, he will be at his sister, Gerdur.

Answer (score 1):

He hangs out in Hod and Gerdur's House which is located behind the Riverwood Trader.

His name is Ralof and if he's not there than it means he's dead (if he can even die).