# How do I complete Bound Until Death without earning a bounty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm at the ***Bound Until Death*** quest for the ***Dark Brotherhood*** and want to do it with the bonus task *(balcony kill)*.

It's not a problem to kill the bride, but I haven't find a place to do it from without getting a 1000 gold *(sometimes +40)* bounty instantly. Everytime the guards will chase me, even when I'm using an invisibility potion.
Of course I'm sneaking and kill her with one shot.

Places I tried:

- other balcony where that bow is
- on the castle wall, going through the church
- from behind her ;-)

**Is it possible to *"stay in the dark"*?**

*Oh, and do I have to worry about my argonian friend?*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go into the temple, up the stairs to the right and out the door up there. You'll end up on the level above the platform. They thank people for coming to their wedding, and you can tip the gargoyle up there on top of her to kill without a bounty.

Whilst this doesn't add a bounty, the husband and the in-laws go ape and try to kill you.

Comment: I found that it was harder to remain undetected after tipping the gargoyle than it was after shooting her.

Answer (score 12):

What I found to work best thus far, was to be ungodly sneaky about it. Not as in "sneak around and try to be undetected" but as in "Use Nightingale Subterfuge" and make the groom kill her instead. :D 
Ofc, provided you have it, but I highly recommend you do. It was the easiest way. No bounty on my head, nobody even paid any notice of me, they were too busy butchering each other, and it's also in the spirit of the mission itself, which was to make them think the stormcloaks did it. ^^

Comment: Freaking brilliant. And call me sentimental... but don't forget to loot the bride and groom.

Answer (score 5):

What I did was:

- Follow her to the balcony
- Get into sneak position
- Nock an arrow
- Just as I let it go hit the B button to take a potion of invisibility

Immediately jump off the balcony to get away. the trick is to use the potion before your arrow hits her.  This way, you won't get a bounty or be chased.

Answer (score 4):

First, get the ability to transform into a werewolf by completing the related Companions quest. Then, in Solitude, find a place where nobody can see you and transform. Kill her, then escape.

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest. Push the gargoyle onto her. Run inside the tower. Immediately press the 'wait' button and do so for 24hrs. Turn walk back outside and fast travel to the dark brotherhood.

Answer (score 2):

Carry some invisibility potions, work pretty well, sniped her from the top of the castle, walked back a bit, drank it, run to an exit, you will need another one on your way, exit, np.

It's with the poisoning later in the questline that I can't find way to avoid bounty...

Answer (score 1):

What I did was I tipped the statue. As soon as I pressed A to tip the staue I took an invisibility potion (50 seconds) before it hit her. I didn't even need to jump off the balcony or anything. The key is to sneak while you're invisible. If you run the guards can hear your footsteps and you'll get a bounty. But if your sneak skill is high enough, and it doesnt have to be very high, you can just sneak right back the way you came. Even when the potion wore off, I was still making my way out of the castle but I was far enough away that the guards didnt suspect anything.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the gargoyle trick or use get your pickpocket to lvl 40 and get the Poisoning perk - you use a frenzy poison on the groom (using the perk not a weapon) and he should kill his wife for you!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is near impossible to remain undetected from your description.

I would rather suggest you to just do the kill and then run as far as possible as you can, make sure to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> to sprint and get an advantage. Then hide somewhere in the bushes or be far enough away so that they will stop chasing you. You can use the Wait system for some days and hope that you get rid of the bounty.

If you have a follower with you, the chance is high that you lose him to the fight.

---

As I'm not near the quest yet, I watched a tutorial.

It seems like the Groom will always notice you even though you are stealthed, he calls the guards downstairs and they will thus always chase you. So... **TL;DR: Run and hide!**

Comment: That'd be sad. _I mean such a low bounty for killing a nobel person, you can even buy a horse for the same money!_
And you can really wait to get rid of the bounty?

Comment: @ordag: [See here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/after-i-stole-their-stuff-how-do-i-survive-from-angry-people/35198#35198). I have tried it and it worked, I didn't had to pay anything when entering the town after waiting 2 hours (for a low bounty), I guess a higher bounty requires more than 2 hours though...

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. _Will be scratch in my career though._

Answer (score 0):

Just go to where the loose gargoyle is, wait for the bride to come, push it, run off for a bit, then quick travel to the brotherhood.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a werewolf simply transform while you're up on the balcony out of sight then jump down where she is standing. She will go inside then come back out and you can kill her, then run out of the city and you will have no bounty.

Just make sure they aren't following you when you turn back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use a means of getting the crowd to do it for you! You can either use a scroll or nightingale subterfuge to cause a MASSIVE battle and hopefully Vittoria will be amongst the casualties(though on my second play-through this didn't work as Vittoria killed her husband and everyone else was busy killing each other).