# Frea is trying to kill me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I've been trying to play the Dragonborn DLC for Skyrim on the PS3. In order to advance the story, I need to talk to Frea and her dad. But every time I go near the village they try and murder me for slaughtering the village back when I was like level 15 (I'm level 43 now).

I've tried yielding but they won't accept it and I don't know how to make them stop, all I want to do is finish the story. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have heard of two different solutions to this problem,
 - Go to Raven Rock and waiting there for 24 hours and going back to the village.
 - Commit a petty crime in Raven Rock and go to jail.

If you are unable to yield to the guards after committing a petty crime (and getting caught), these might help

[How do I get rid of my bounty?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/how-do-i-get-rid-of-my-bounty/45295#45295)

[How do I stop the Riften Guards from killing me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52149/how-do-i-stop-the-riften-guards-from-killing-me)

Comment: So that worked but now I can't start the fate of the Skaal, also finished a long time ago, any thing you recommend me trying, I've tried rereading the black books and revisiting the temple to no avail.

Comment: @user136496 I see you made a new question about this, I shall attempt to answer it there. If this worked for you, you can hit the check mark on my answer to mark it as correct so others know this worked.