# Can't go to jail

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was in the jarls palace in whiterun and "accidentally" took an item called "unusual gem."
Now every time I go to whiterun then I get massacred by a huge group of guards and if I kill anybody I'll just be digging myself into a bigger hole. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of my bounty?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/how-do-i-get-rid-of-my-bounty)

Comment: The guards should confront you and provide you with options. Go to Jail, Resist Arrest, Persuade Guard, Declare Thaneship and Bribe. **Some** of the options will not be available. Your _unusual gem_ is probably one of 24 _Stones of Barenziah_.

Answer (score 1):

Just taking that item (Which is a quest item) shouldn't cause them to attack you.. However. Draw your weapon then put it away, if it really is just a minor infraction over the limit they should also put their weapons away and then confront you to let you pay off the debt or go to jail.