# On second thought, I'm tired of guards killing me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently posted a question, "How do I get the Worst Reputation possible" For Skyrim, I followed all of your helpful tips community, and everyone is out to get me. Alas, I am tired of my life of crime and would like to know: Are there any exact quests that make people act more positive when you walk near? i.e. Change the usual statement they make when you pass by? And other stuff like that. Because apparently being the Dragon Born Hero is not good enough for these people!

Comment: I feel like you would enjoy Fable

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of my bounty?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/how-do-i-get-rid-of-my-bounty)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz This question has nothing to do with bounties or hostile NPCs.

Answer (score 5):

Only guards comment on your feats (positive ones), such as:

- Completing the main quest
- Joining a faction (such as dark brotherhood etc)
- Having a high proficiency in a skill (destruction, alteration, lockpicking, etc)
- The local guards will comment on local quest completions

etc

Other NPCs in the world will not comment on anything you've done, unless their specific scripted to that event. For example, completing a quest for an NPC may cause them to have a different dialog for you when you walk past them or interact with them.

Comment: "Is that... fur? Coming out of your ears?"

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Other than usual quests/persuasion...

- [This](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=14152) mod adds a "house" in game inside you have many
  cheats...one of them will be to reset your reputation/bounty.

If people are still attacking you(sometimes parts of your bounty stays up even if people don't attack you so you could try some of this just in case):

- Declare Thaneship If you are the Thane of a hold, you can declare
  this to the guard. This will immediately clear your bounty (if the
  bounty is less than 3000 gold), but can only be done once per hold
  (twice if the hold is captured during the civil war and you are made a Thane by the new Jarl).
- If the guards don't give you a chance to submit,persuade,go to jail or pay
  your bounty make sure that you sheath your weapon. The guards should
  then stop attacking and you should hopefully hear your out.If they
  don't you can try u sing a strong enough Calm spell to stop
  the guards from attacking, though speaking to them results in an
  arrest attempt. Another method is to punch an innocent person, keep
  your fists raised and then try to yield again.
- Using console command `player.setcrimegold 0 (id of city)` [more](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29) info.