# How to clean high bounty without losing skill progress?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

## SPOILER INCOMING!

<sub>Prepare yourself for spoilers...</sub>

After Dark Brotherhood quest for killing the REAL emperor, I killed Maro; then my bounty become 3,500 septims and (I don't know how) 1,000 bounty in Whiterun. Now, I can't get my stuff in Breezehome and transport to Markareth and can't enter Solitude. How can I clean this high bounty without losing my skills?

Comment: I assume paying it isn't an option then... Are you a member of the thieves guild in riften? That could help. Also, have you already pulled the 'thane' card in Whiterun?

Comment: Yep (2 questions), but I used my Thanehood in Whiterun :/

Comment: Oh, paying *IS* one option.

Comment: Something of a **spoiler alert** would have been nice...

Comment: @kotekzot Nope, this question add the following: ` How can I clean this high bounty without losing my skills?` - **without losing my skills**?

Comment: That's just a subset of the previous question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When confronted with a bounty, you have several options, which are detailed [in the answer to this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/how-do-i-get-rid-of-my-bounty)

In your particular case, you can't declare Thaneship.  You've also indicated that you'd rather not lose skill progress.

In this case, you still have several options:

- If you've got cash on hand, you could just pay it off.  The guards will leave you alone at this point.  No harm, no foul.
- If you have some thief skills, you could get caught.  If you sleep in the bed, you'll lose progress in some number of skills towards the next level, *but* if you break out then it's all good.  This does clear your inventory, however, and you'll have to sneak to get your stuff back.  Your "owned" items are returned, but if you want your "stolen" items back, you'll need to pick a pretty hard lock.  In some cases, people have reported issues after having their inventory cleared.  I'd suggest saving first.
- If you're "in" with the Thieves' Guild, you can bribe the guards, which is often cheaper than paying off a particularly high bounty.  However, getting the bribe option requires that you've already completed some quests for the guild in that particular hold.  Not something you could fix if you haven't done it already, but an option to consider for the future.

With regards to skill loss:  you will not lose entire points, just progress towards your next point.  So if your one-handed is at 50 and you're halfway to 51, you *might* lose that halfway to 51 progress, but you will *not* go from level 50 to level 49.

In my opinion, the far more irritating part is the glitches that sometimes occur when your inventory is dumped into the chest, and the potential difficulty of recovering any items marked as "stolen."

Comment: @Vaishali *yoink* I stole your emoticon:  :-P

Comment: I'm rich, so I'll pay :P. I'm not a pro on Skyrim, but I played for 2 years. This is the first time that I got a giant bounty like that, and my archery is like 98 and almost 99, so pay ;).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common occurrence.

I just killed the Emperor on his ship.

My bounty was zero before I did this.

After killing the Emperor never detected with sneak = 100 and invisibility, I fast traveled to Falkreath. All guards were hostile. I displayed my Thane-ship. (Bounty was 1600 in Falkreath)

Exited the game without saving.

Replayed it instead of Falkreath, fast traveled to Solitude. All guards were hostile. Paid off my bounty. (Bounty was 5400)

I can not test any further without starting a new character and getting to kill the emperor will take much time.

I am leaving this answer here since I can not rule out arbitrary events.

Comment: Paying my bounty will reset my skills?