# Skyrim Bounty Help

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I killed my wife and guards attacked me non stop. I killed them and I got more and more bounty on me. now I have about 10,000 on my head.

How long do I wait to get the bounty off me?

Comment: I've accidentally gone on a murderous rampage. What should I do?

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/how-do-i-get-rid-of-my-bounty?rq=1) should probably be able to answer your question, and yours is probably a duplicate. It implies that simply waiting won't do anything if your bounty is too high.