# How to clear a 2000+ bounty in the reach?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a 2130 bounty in the reach. A Bounty Hunter approached me and I paid him and then killed him. Now, every time I try to clear my debt outright, the game freezes. Is there any way to prevent this?  I have my weapon sheathed when they approach.

Comment: This might not be a complete duplicate of [said question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/how-do-i-get-rid-of-my-bounty), but, if so, can you expand on what you have tried so far, and when the freezing takes place exactly? Did you only try paying the bounty, or **opt for going to jail** as well?

Comment: Are you running any mods?