# How to finish a quest after the NPC you need to deliver it to, has become hostile to you?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I killed a bunch of people in Whiterun, so the guards were hostile. I then started the quest where the innkeeper joins you to kill a dragon. When we passed some guards, they started attacking me. As well as the innkeeper. I went on to kill the dragon, and now I need to deliver the quest to the hostile innkeeper. Any way to finish this now, without turning myself in?

Comment: @TomWijsman The questions may be similar, but I wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Comment: @Wipqozn: I don't think we really want a bunch of "what-to-do-with-my-bounty" Qs with the same answer.

Comment: @Tom The term is "exact duplicate". This isn't. The right answer might be "get rid of your bounty first", or there might be another option. Nowhere does this question ask how to get rid of a bounty.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: It indirectly does ask so, it is required to lose the hostility of the innkeeper. You can write this situation in a thousand ways, you don't have to explicitly list that there is a bounty that has to be dealt with; it is still the same problem with the exact same symptons...

Comment: Well, how would i know if i could maybe still talk to the innkeeper by doing certain things?

Comment: @SimonVerbeke: The question I suggested makes it clear that these kind of actions don't make you welcome in the town anymore, the answer provided there explains how to rid of the bounty or at least get it decreased just by simply running away and hiding. There have been some questions that are all based on "I have some situation (that involves a bounty), how do I succeed (removing the bounty)", and I believe yet more will come. I could stop suggesting my duplicate votes, but then people are just reinventing the wheel by writing new answers. Anyhow, glad that you resolved it. Veel plezier! :)

Comment: @Tom Like I said, the close requirement is *"exact"*, so indirect doesn't cut it. Also, that other question is yours—there's some possibility of bias on your part, which isn't helped by the fact that you're the only user saying these questions are duplicates. Never fear: you're not the only person here responsible for finding duplicates.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: We've already closed another one; please note that closing on Gaming does take a considerable amount of time. It's a bit harsh to state that I'm the only user as well as the owner of that question. I know the Stack Exchange system well enough to know how duplicates are determined, and that they are closed by voting. I don't need to discuss this with you; your "exact duplicate" logic does not make any sense to me, in that way there wouldn't even be a single duplicate. Don't bother; this way, we are never going to agree on this anyway...

Comment: @Tom Okay. It's just, you're protesting… a lot. You don't need to discuss it with me, no; but nor do you need to argue quite so much with others. \*shrug\* Anyway, what I mean by "my" logic is [Jeff's own words on the meaning of "exact duplicate" on stackexchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I don't see `exact` defined here; although he does mention only 4 or so original questions. I'm mainly here trying to prevent a flood of more of them (we are two days into this game, surely more questions that are [in]directly about getting rid of a bounty will come), let me quote a sentence from the blog post: `But not enough question duplication is also bad.` As said, voting should naturally get the right questions closed as a duplicate of the main SEO questions, I'm just lowering the amount of votes required to do so as I'm opposed to giving duplicate answers...

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Please do note that I'm just linking *possible duplicates*, I did not start any arguments other than explaining my thoughts in a single sentence. It's pretty natural for opposite voters to start protesting when you state "This isn't an exact duplicate.", that's why we vote for things. So we don't have to endlessly argue about it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to talk to the innkeeper, [you should get rid of your bounty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/after-i-murdered-robbed-people-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-bounty/35198#35198). Then, you can deliver your quest.

Answer (score 5):

You could try casting the spell "Calm" on him...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation arise due to the Markarth glitch. I used the shadow cloak of nocturnal power to sneak past all the guards and get into the room. It's been my experience that unless the guards see you and turn hostile, the npc's won't.

Answer (score 1):

Well what I do, is I'll stay away for a while, then come back later. Next, I go up to a guard, who will say, "Wait, I know you." And join the Thieves Guild so you have the option to say "I'm with the guild, how about you look the other way?" The guild is easy to join so it won't waste time. You'll be able to skip out on other crimes like Thievery. So I hope this helps you, all hostile allies will not attack with you having no bounty.