# I have a huge bounty in Skyrim, how do I get rid of it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After I murdered/robbed people, how do I get rid of the bounty?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/after-i-murdered-robbed-people-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-bounty)

So I killed an entire major city in Skyrim (I forget the name of it) and have a 38,000 bounty in that area. The guards won't even say anything if I sheath my weapon so I just end up killing them again and the bounty gets bigger. How do I get rid of this without reloading?

Comment: Mark Trapp puts it best in that question's answer: "Game over man." Anyways, since this is a duplicate, I'm going to close this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest sleeping or waiting a day or two in game, then going to the town without any weapons drawn. That should let the guards talk to you, with a debt that great though I'm not sure if jail is an option. Might require more waiting..