# How to get back to werewolf in Ring Of Hircine quest-line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am stuck with the damn Ring Of Hircine and I believe I've *almost* completed the quest. I think I have killed the werewolf when I was supposed to (if I *was* supposed to), but now I can't get to him because I killed him in the jail cell. I think I also have Telekenesis, but everyone in Skyrim hates me because **I accidentally killed Alvor and failed the game so I just went on as a Rogue because I got so much stuff since then and didn't want to restart the game.**

I can't get into Falkreath because everyone will attack me and Telekenesis takes **a lot** of Magicka for me. (I've been recently thinking of attacking Falkreath with brute force and raw power, but there are so many people.)

I'm a level 36 Orc with:

- A complete set of superior, enchanted, Orish armor (with the exception of the helmet/mask)
- Nahkrin (I think it is enchanted with Destruction and Restoration spells cost 25% less and Magicka is increased by 50 points) with an armor rating of 49 or 50
- A superior (or maybe flawless) glass warhammer that does like 69-75 damage
- A superior ebony bow (and almost all arrows - and an abundant amount - except daedric and Dwarven Sphere arrows)

Should I attack Falkreath? **If I succeed, how would I get to the werewolf in the jail cell?** Otherwise, how can I get back to the werewolf in the jail cell to complete the Ring Of Hircine quest?

Comment: Well...the other ones don't have all of Skyrim/Tamriel after them and also they don't ask how to get into the jail cell :I

Comment: The current state of the question makes it sound like this is mostly about "am I strong enough to break into Falkreath?" with a small element of "is it possible to revisit this NPC, given my current circumstances?". Focusing the question on the latter might be more likely to produce a concrete answer. There are probably too many variables involved to realistically answer the first part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to solve your murder problem instead of trying to continue like this. You won't really be able to continue *the game* if "all of Tamriel" is trying to kill you, nevermind just this one quest. We have a number of questions and answers that can help; here's just one: **[After I murdered/robbed people, how do I get rid of the bounty?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/after-i-murdered-robbed-people-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-bounty)**

Failing that, as a short-term solution you should consider locating or brewing a good invisibility potion, and just sneak into the prison.

As a long term solution, *save often and to different slots*. Skyrim (and all BethSoft games) are not linear, and you can easily make it hard or impossible to continue a quest you'd like to do, nevermind the problems if you run into bugs and don't have an earlier save. Always make saves that you can go back to, and make them often enough that you won't lose "so much stuff" that you won't want to reload.

Comment: What do you mean "Skyrim (and all BethSoft games) are not linear"?