# I killed everyone help

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I killed a bunch of guards and villagers and now everyone hates me, and the NPC's have not respawned. How to I get them to like me again and get the guards to respawn?

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a two parter question. The first is already answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/after-i-murdered-robbed-people-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-bounty). The second:

Sadly, named NPCs do not respawn. Unnamed NPCS (like Guards) do respawn after a few days.

---

There's something else of note:

Clearing a bounty doesn't make people like you, each NPC has a hidden "affection" value towards the player, which can be decreased by them witnessing/being victims of crimes commited by the player, but increased by side quests. Not all NPCs offer side quests.

Not having a bounty stops people (mainly guards) from attacking you on sight